# What will happen once Windows Live Messenger retire?

Tags: skype, windows-live-messenger

As per the [news](http://blogs.skype.com/en/2012/11/skypewlm.html)...

> Our goal remains to deliver the best communications experience for everyone, everywhere. We want to focus our efforts on making things simpler for our users while continuously improving the overall experience. **We will retire Messenger** in all countries worldwide in the first quarter of 2013 (with the exception of mainland China where Messenger will continue to be available).

Does it means that the software will stop working or that it will stop being supported?

Will I really have to use Skype or will 3rd-party software still work?

Will it be possible to avoid merging accounts, yet continu to use both? (My Skype is a clean ~10 contacts list, while my msn is a ~200 people mess.)

Comment: Retired = No worky

Comment: I thought everyone stopped using messenger when I did. - - - Export your contacts, install Pidgin, create a new account (on whatever) and find them again (wherever they are).

Comment: That's kind of part of my question too : Would pidgin "msn part" stop working too? (And according to Isaac answer, yes). And uh, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Messenger will stop working.

Messenger is a [client/server application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model). The client part is the program that runs on your computer. The server part is the program that runs on Microsoft's [server hardware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_(computing)). Without the server hardware running the server software, the client software cannot function.

Answer (score 2):

Skype is using the WLM backend, so there won't necessarily be a complete shutdown of the WLM API.